# Unsure how to calculate the variables stated

Tags: java, calculator

```
    double Euro = 1.37;
    double USAD = 1.81;
    double JapYen = 190.00;
    double Zloty = 5.88;

    //First menu choice screen
    if (MenuChoice == 1) {
        System.out.println("Which of the following currencies do you wish to exchange into sterling?");
        System.out.println("Euro - EUR");
        System.out.println("USA Dollar - USD");
        System.out.println("Japanese Yen - JPY");
        System.out.println("Polish Zloty - PLN");
        System.out.print("Please enter the three letter currency:   ");

        //Currency input validation
        String CurChoice = "";
        boolean isCorrectCurrency = false;
        do {
            CurChoice = keybStr.next();
            isCorrectCurrency = CurChoice.matches("^EUR|USD|JPY|PLN$");

            if (isCorrectCurrency) {
                System.out.println("");
            } else {
                System.out.print("Invalid Currency Entered. Please Retry: ");
            }

        } while (!isCorrectCurrency);

        //Exchange amount calculator
        System.out.print("Enter the amount you wish to exchange of " + CurChoice + ": ");
        double ExcAmount = keybStr.nextInt();

        if (CurChoice == "EUR") {
            double result = ExcAmount / Euro;
            System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + " = £" + result);
        } else if (CurChoice == "USD") {
            double result = ExcAmount / USAD;
            System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + " = £" + result);
        } else if (CurChoice == "JPY") {
            double result = ExcAmount / JapYen;
            System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + " = £" + result);
        } else if (CurChoice == "PLN") {
            double result = ExcAmount / Zloty;
            System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + " = £" + result);
        } else {
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }//if
```

So this is what I got so far. I want the code to say (as an example) "500.00 in EUR = £364.96" though when I run the code it just ends after the user inputs which currency they wish to use. Any help? I wasn't sure whether i needed to put the if statement within a loop or something.

Comment: Hint: using `==` with Strings, or objects in general, is almost never correct. (Why this is not a mandated compiler warning after years of bugs still surprises me.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: So how would I go about amending my piece of code to add the .equalsTo

Comment: It doesn't even prompt them for the amount to exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) using `==` for strings checks if they are the same item. In this case even though both `CurChoice` and one of the literal strings `"EUR"` may have the same value it will still be **false** as this is comparing references. So what's happening is they are all false and the system prints out a blank line from the `else`. To fix this use `.equals()` for your comparisons.

```
    if (CurChoice.equals("EUR")) {
        double result = ExcAmount / Euro;
        System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + " = £" + result);
    } else if (CurChoice.equals("USD")) {
        double result = ExcAmount / USAD;
        System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + " = £" + result);
    } else if (CurChoice.equals("JPY")) {
        double result = ExcAmount / JapYen;
        System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + " = £" + result);
    } else if (CurChoice.equals("PLN")) {
        double result = ExcAmount / Zloty;
        System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + " = £" + result);
    } else {
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 1.7+, switch also works:

```
switch (CurChoice) {
case "EUR":
    double result = ExcAmount / Euro;
    System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + " = £" + result);
    break;
case "USD":
    double result = ExcAmount / USAD;
    System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + " = £" + result);
    break;
...
default:
    System.out.println("");
}
```

But the best approach is to set all currency code and exchange rate into a map, e.g.

```
HashMap<String, Double> = new HashMap<>();
curMap.put("EUR", Euro);
curMap.put("USD", USAD);
...
Double rate = curMap.get(CurChoice);
if (rate == null) {
    System.out.println("");
} else {
    double result = ExcAmount / Double.valueOf(rate);
    System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + " = £" + result);
}
```